# How do you pass multiple scopes when using the Maven dependency plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I want a list of runtime, compile and provided dependencies when using mvn dependency:list. I want to exclude dependencies with a test scope. "includeScope" has runtime and compile options, I want a union of the two. Is there a parameter I can use to achieve this?

Comment: You could use `excludeScope=test`

Comment: excludeScope=test doesn't work because it excludes all dependencies